# Spark Generate A Lot Of Tasks Although Partition Number is 1 Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My code:

```
df = self.sql_context.sql(f"select max(id) as id from {table}")
return df.collect()[0][0]
```

My table is partitioned by id - it has 100M records but only 3 distinct id's. 
I expected this query to work with 1 task and scan just the partition column (id). 
I don't understand how I have 691 tasks for the collect line with just 3 partitions 
I guess the query is executing full scan on the table but I can't figure why it doesn't scan just the metadata

Answer (score 0):

Your `df` contains the result of an aggregation on the entire table, it contains only one row (with only one field being the `max(id)`), this is why it has only 1 partition.

But the original `table` DataFrame may have many partitions (or only 1 partition but its computation needs ~600 stages, triggering 1 task per stage, which is not that common)

Without details on your parallelism configurations and input source type and transformations, it is not easy to help more !

Comment: So how can I control the number of the partitions generated in the sql query?
I understand your explanation about the reason I get 1 when I print it - but is it possible to control the number of partition the spark sql is generating?
 @Enzo

Comment: You can read about these configurations keys: `spark.default.parallelism` and  `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`